# Is it possible to define a differential function differently?

Tags: derivatives

When differentiating y w.r.t. x when y is a function of x, we write:

$\lim\limits_{\delta x \to 0}(\frac{\delta y}{\delta x})=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Instead, can we write the following (since as $\delta x$ approaches 0, so does $\delta y$)?

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim\limits_{\delta y \to 0}(\frac{\delta y}{\delta x})$

If this is incorrect, why?

Comment: "since as δx approaches 0, so does δy" - are you sure about that?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm only a high schooler; so, I guess I'm not entirely sure. If I'm wrong, what does happen to delta y as delta x approaches 0?

Comment: Your definition is not quite right. The proper definition would be: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}$$ where $y(x)$ is the value of the function at the point $x$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Let $$y=x^2$$

We have $$\delta y = ( x+\delta x )^2 - x^2 = \delta x ( 2x + \delta x)$$ As you notice, $\delta y =0$, if  $2x + \delta x =0$ without $\delta x$ approaching $0$